# How to change Angular 10 library build structure

Tags: angular, directory-structure, angular10, angular-library

I'm maintaining an Angular 10 Ivy library and I'm attempting to upgrade it to make use of Secondary Entrypoints, but I'm running into trouble with folder structure of the final build.

Ideally, the folder structure would emulate @angular's folder structure of:

```
-node_modules
 |
  -- @angular
     |
     --core
     --common
     --cli
     --material
     ...
```

and I could import pieces of the library like: `import { someModule } from '@angular/core';`

My current library builds with a folder structure of

```
-node_modules
 |
  --myLibrary
    |
     --package.json
     --dist/myLibrary
       |
        --package.json
        --public_api.ts
        --myLibrary.d.ts
        --feature1
        --feature2
        --feature3
        ...
```

which forces me to import features like `import { feature1Module} from 'myLibrary/dist/myLibrary/feature1';`.

I know I can remove the second `myLibrary` folder by updating the `dest` path in my `myLibrary/ng-package.json`, but the I don't know how to remove the `dist` folder to make everything build on the same level, as setting `"dest": "../.."` will fail to build.

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/myLibrary",
  "assets": [
    "quill/*.scss"
  ]
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

**Update:**
The project structure is

```
-projects
 |
  --myLibrary
    |
     --package.json
     --ng-package.json
     --src
       |
        --public_api.ts
        --commonFunctions
     --feature1
       |
       --package.json
       --src
         |
         --public_api.ts
         --index.ts
         --feature1.component.ts
         --feature1.component.html
         --feature1.module.ts
     --feature2
     --feature3
     ...
```

My `projects/myLibrary/src/public_api.ts` only exports the functions in `commonFunctions` and each of the `public_api.ts` files in each of the feature folders only exports the modules and components of their respective features.

Comment: Is feature module 1 exported from the library public api? If so, can it just be an import like import { featuremodule1 } from “my-library”? It’s similar to how you would import core angular modules like httpclient from some dist path.

Comment: No, feature1 is exported only through it's own public_api.ts file. From my understanding, if feature1 were exported from the library's primary public_api.ts then feature1 would be always be imported into a consuming project regardless of if that project actually used feature1. This would defeat the purpose of using secondary entrypoints.

Comment: In case of angular each `@angular/*` is a separate package. If you deliver multiple packages via `my-package/pkg1` you might achieve that folder structure. Not otherwise. Also it wouldn't make any sense to have that structure apart from gathering multiple packages of your own production in one place

Comment: @Sergey, Thank you for the response! Please take a look at the `@angular/material` library. My end goal is to allow for imports from `myLibrary/feature1`, similar to how `@angular/material` allows imports from `@angular/material/buttons`. Reading through the documentation in ng-packagr on secondary endpoints, this should be possible (https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/secondary-entrypoints.md)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my issue.

My issue is that I am importing my library into my projects as a github dependency instead of as an npm package. I do this because Github allows users to host private repositories for free, but NPM requires a paid monthly subscription for private packages, so our company's work-around was to add our private library's dependency like `"my-library": "git+ssh://git@github.com/myOrg/my-library.git#semver:10.2.7"`. This actually works when you are not implementing secondary entrypoints since your primary entrypoint points to a definitions file that gets built with all the library features and has proper signposts to those features.

The structure of the built module becomes an issue when you try implementing secondary entrypoints, since ng-packagr does not traverse more than a single layer down in your module's structure when searching for the additional `package.json` files that denote the secondary entrypoints. After reading https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2974 it seems like npm doesn't support installing projects from subdirectories, and instead just looks for the first `package.json` file it finds in the repository and installs that as the module. This is what gives me the weird folder structure since the repository is actually a mono-repo that hosts my-library, a demo project, and an e2e testing project. Since there is no supported way to install just one of those projects individually, my possible solutions are limited to either breaking the library out into it's own Github repo or writing a `postinstall` script that will copy/paste the contents of `node_modules/myLibrary/dist/myLibrary` into `node_modules/myLibrary`

Comment: looks like postinstall scripts don't actually work with windows right now since npm runs it's postinstall script in appdata/roaming instead of in the actual project that is running npm install. Sadly, the solution is to host a private github repo that is just the build artifact from the library.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar folder structure, in my library I have Input, Button...etc, which is called features like your said. And in ng-package.json I have the settings like below:

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/ngx-pluto",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/index.ts",
    "cssUrl": "inline"
  }
}
```

And in my feature table.module.ts I can import NpPaginatorModule feature like below:

```
import { NpPaginatorModule } from '../paginator/index';
```

And after I use npm published my library I can import my feature in my consuming project like below:

```
import { NpButtonModule } from 'ngx-pluto';
```

Here is my code link just for your reference:
https://github.com/KevinZhang19870314/pluto-ui

Comment: Hey Kevin, I appreciate your response but your library only has one entry point and sadly doesn't help me. The issue I am having is a result of migrating my library over to use secondary entry points which make my library features tree-shakable. In your library, if a consuming application only uses your 'button' feature, it still imports every other feature in your library. This is bad in my case since some of my features have large 3rd party dependencies that I'd rather not require a consuming application to download when it doesn't use that feature.

Comment: No no, in my library, if you want to use 'Button' only, you just need to imports NpButtonModule, no other modules need to be imported. That's why I featured those controls. And if you have some 3rd party dependencies, you need to import it to your specific feature, and this 3rd party denpencies will use as bundledDependencies in your library's package.json file (like this https://github.com/KevinZhang19870314/pluto-ui/blob/master/projects/ngx-pluto/package.json). When you build you consuming app with installed library, only imported feature will be bundled by angular cli I think.

Comment: Your library actually isn't tree-shakable. Take a look at your public-api.ts file (https://github.com/KevinZhang19870314/pluto-ui/blob/master/projects/ngx-pluto/src/public-api.ts). This forces your library to make all of your features available to a consuming application all of the time. If you were able to use Dynamic Imports, technically you could get around large 3rd party dependencies by making them optionalDependencies and not adding them to the consuming application, but I do not have that luxury because I have to support IE11 and ES5 doesnt have Dynamic Imports.

Comment: Here, this article might help explain secondary entrypoints better than I can in a comment. https://medium.com/tunaiku-tech/creating-secondary-entry-points-for-your-angular-library-1d5c0e95600a

Comment: Does thsi solve your problem?https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/900#issuecomment-582920739